# What to use instead of global variables in python? The value of the global variable changes during runtime

Tags: python, tkinter

What to use instead of global variables in python? The value of the global variable changes during runtime.

I have a file: mygui.py where global variables are used and their value is changed during runtime.

mygui.py

```
#gui with tkinter

import globals

globals.VAR1 = True
globals.VAR2 = 123

# some gui stuff happens

globals.VAR1 = False
globals.VAR2 = 3212231

# another gui stuff happens based on new values
```

globals.py

```
globals.VAR1 = False
globals.VAR2 = 111
```

How do I implement this without needing of globals, so without needing the file globals.py? I am using the global values during runtime and the app is dependent on these globals. So I need to store the values somewhere and have them available all the time.

Comment: Unless you can keep values by passing them to and returning them from various functions will will need some kind of 'global' mechanism which isn't necessarily a simple global variable. You could, for example, use a database or pickle. What is your aversion to using global variables?

Comment: I wanted to try to respect "good practices" and not to use globals in the app. Your statement "Unless you can keep values by passing them to and returning them from various functions" seems interesting to me. Maybe you can provide an example?

Comment: Do you know how to pass values to and from functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables, with `os.environ` that is a dictionary.[Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ)